# Add USB Bluetooth to mPCIE card?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth, network-adapter

So I bought the Azurewave AW-CE123H AC + BT 4.0 wifi card for my laptop, and found out that the Bluetooth section of the card communicates via USB. There were warnings that not all mPCIE slots accommodate USB but I took the risk - only to find out that there is no connection to USB with my laptop's port (found this out through no USB devices appearing in Device Manager).

Downloading the AW-CE123H's manual ([which can be found here](https://techship.se/products/azurewave-aw-ce123h/)) and looking at the pin-out, I found USB D+ and D- lines at pins 36 and 38. Looking at my previous installed wifi cards, I noticed that pins 36 and 38 weren't connected to anything, and probing around on the connector I found the connectors that accept these pins weren't connected to anything either.

This all got me thinking, **Could I solder connections to these pins (36 and 38) and connect them to another USB port to activate Bluetooth?** Is that what the USB D+ and D- lines on the card are used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LISTEN UP FAM!

It turns out that my laptop could support USB in the PCIE adapter the whole time, but since I removed the BIOS white-list to make the card work, it was disabling the Bluetooth module, hence the reason why it was not showing up in device manager.

The solution to getting the AW-CE123H card to work was to tape over pins 5 and 51, the Bluetooth disable pins. I let Device manager do its thing and we good!

Hope you all can learn something.